# Does this answer in CV imply advertisement?

Tags: discussion

I was going through [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-to-find-patterns-and-identify-changes-in-them-in-time-series-with-r) and it seems to me that @Tom Reilly is promoting his own business along with the answer to OP's question. Is this considered OK in CV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

Comment: What do the people of CV Meta site think about it? That's probably a more apt place to ask.

Comment: I don't know the CV-rules, so I'll keep this as a comment - but IMO his answer needs a little cleaning up, but is otherwise extensive and seems as if he has put quite a lot of effort into it. If he feels like mentioning that his business is in the same area I'd say he earned it. It falls into the "Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it." that is linked in @benisuǝqbackwards comment, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Anders UP gave a good answer in a comment to the question.  The concern behind the question is that answers involving a product someone is closely connected with *could* be less than objective.  That's a legitimate concern, so moderators and engaged users do our best to identify such connections and reveal them to the community.  When the answerer discloses their connection to any product or service used or recommended in their answer, all readers have the information they need to make their own judgments about possible conflicts of interest. That should lay the concern to rest.

If we were to prevent everyone who has ever released software or patented a method or written a book from writing about it or using it, we wouldn't have any experts left to share their knowledge and insights.  I wish we had more Tom Reillys making such contributions.

Comment: +1 Indeed, he's not the only regular contributor here with an intimate connection to that particular software; generally speaking, I value their expertise and level of contribution very highly -- probably even more so than some of the recipients of their wisdom (sometimes it's not obvious to a novice how good the help is). Basically, they're giving away a large amount of high-level help on particular topics (as are many here). Perhaps there's occasional straying close to various lines here and there, but the mods have been proactive at suggesting ways to bring responses into conformity...

Comment: ctd ... I'm very glad they're here, and contributing.